# Prepending _Variable_ Folder Names to a List of Files

Tags: awk, scripting

Given a text file containing:

```
AF002 AI003 AA001 AD005 AD006 AI002 …
```

(separated by record separators)

Produce a text file containing the following:

```
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
…
```

(separated by the same record separators)

In other words, infer the path from the first two letters of the filename, and append .jpg

Another desired feature is that, since I will be handling scores of such files, to test that the first three entries in the input file are [A-F][A-Z][0-1].  That would preclude my accidentally applying the script to an output file, since the third character (/) would fail the test.

I have been trying to create an AWK script to do this on my iMac, but can't seem to get even the simplest things to work.  I would like to have the script in a separate command file.  I am facing a deadline.

Comment: When you can simply do this with shell builtin, I do not see any need to call external program like AWK here. Look at the answer of @Giles Quenot for more details.

Comment: When you say `separated by record separators` - do you mean each string is on a line of it's own? If so, show that in the sample input, don't put them all on one line. If that's NOT what you mean then please clarify what you do mean.

Comment: Thanks to those who responded.  I especially like the bash script solution, but I didn't know echo could be used in this way.  I specified "record separators" to clarify that it wasn't field separators.  I was having trouble formatting my original post to include the carriage returns.  Thanks again to all for saving my bacon!

Answer (score 2):

like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$(<file)

for i in $str; do
    if [[ $i =~ ^[A-F][A-Z][0-1] ]]; then
        echo "${i:0:2}/$i.jpg"
    fi
done
```

### Output

```
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```

Comment: Or in one line: `read -a str <<< $(< file.txt) && for i in ${str[@]}; do
    [[ $i =~ ^[A-F][A-Z][0-1] ]] && echo "${i:0:2}/$i.jpg"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print substr($i,1,2)"/"$i".jpg" }' file.txt

AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```

- `for` to loop over each field.
- `substring` to print the first 2 char of each field.

Comment: OP asked validation regex `[A-F][A-Z][0-1].`

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pne "s/ /\n/g" p| awk '{print substr($1,1,2)"/"$0".jpg"}'
```

output

```
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```

Comment: OP asked validation regex `[A-F][A-Z][0-1].`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `separated by record separators` means your input strings are actually newline-separated:

```
$ awk '/^[A-F][A-Z][0-1]/{print substr($0,1,2) "/" $0 ".jpg"}' file
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```

If not then with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '/^[A-F][A-Z][0-1]/{print substr($0,1,2) "/" $0 ".jpg"}' file
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```

or take your pick with any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' '/^[A-F][A-Z][0-1]/{sub(/\n/,""); print substr($0,1,2) "/" $0 ".jpg"}' file
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg

$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^[A-F][A-Z][0-1]/) print substr($i,1,2) "/" $i ".jpg"}' file
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg

$ tr ' ' $'\n' < file | awk '/^[A-F][A-Z][0-1]/{print substr($0,1,2) "/" $0 ".jpg"}'
AF/AF002.jpg
AI/AI003.jpg
AA/AA001.jpg
AD/AD005.jpg
AD/AD006.jpg
AI/AI002.jpg
```